# Is there a simple way to write only not null parameters with string.format

Tags: c#, string, format

Instead of writing something like this

```
if(param!=null){
   string message = String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}, Param: {2}" time,someaction,param)
}else{                                                                   
string message = String.Format("Time:{0},Action:{1}" time,someaction);
```

can i write

```
string message = String.Format(("Time: {0}, Action: {1}, Param: {2}!=null" time,someaction,param)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this is nice and tidy if you are using a vs 2015+ / c#6 
Coalesce with string interpolation

```
var message = $"Time: {time}, Action: {someaction}" + (param != null ? $", Param: {param}" : "");
```

Comment: var message = $"Time: {time}, Action: {someaction}" + (param != null ? $", Param: {param}" : "");

Comment: i needed to add brackets after +, but thanks for this classy idea :)

Comment: Typed on my phone. Glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can write this

```
string message = param != null 
    ? String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}, Param: {2}" time, someaction, param)
    : String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}" time, someaction);
```

It's called [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) and is a nice way to shorten if else statements.

In C# 6 you can shorten your `String.Format` as well; for example

```
$"Time: {time}, Action: {someaction}, Param: {param}"
```

instead of

```
String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}, Param: {2}" time, someaction, param)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like :

```
string message = String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}{2}",
    time,
    someaction,
    param ? String.Format(", Param: {0}",param) : ""  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is:

```
string message = String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}, " + 
                 (param != null ? " Param: {2}" : string.Empty), 
                  time, someaction, param);
```

It looks a little unreadable though.

The idea is basically to add a further string and placeholder for the third parameter into the string only if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the other answers but you can try this as well:

```
string message = String.Format("Time: {0}, Action: {1}{2}",time,someaction,param==null?"":
                 String.Format(", param : {0}",param) );
```

Here we are adding the `param` as another formatted string, and are included to the actual output only is the item is not null. Hope that this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvVKEE) will explain things clearer than my words. Please take a look